# How to implement rate and review functionality in my restaurant finder app made using foursquare api?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, foursquare, review

we are developing an restaurant locater application using foursquare api. We get the details of restaurant from foursquare.I wanted to know if it is possible for our users to rate and review a particular restaurant. does the api support it?? if not what alternate solution can you suggest.

Comment: I am also interested in pulling reviews from foursquare API. Doesn't seem like it is possible. Can anyone from foursquare chime in here?

Comment: I guess, we can get existing reviews from foursquare database but cant post our own reviews,

Comment: Is it an aspect on a venue or another API call? Didn't see it in the docs

Comment: It's available in venue details